# Mocking service within service in Angular/Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

In this Angular/Jasmine code I have one controller and two services, `service1` and `service2`. The controller calls `service1` and `service1` calls `service2`.

I'm trying to mock `service2` while unit testing the controller, without mocking `service1`. Is this possible?

This is my attempt (that doesn't work) in a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rkr8hQqtdBW85BMCbrrW?p=preview):

```
angular.module("myModule", [])

.service('service1', function(service2){
    this.sum = function(num1,num2) {
        return service2.theRealSum(num1,num2);
    };
})

.service('service2', function(){
    this.theRealSum = function(num1,num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    };
})


.controller('ctl', function($scope,$timeout,service1) {
      $scope.sumTheTwo = function (num1,num2){
        $scope.result = service1.sum(num1,num2);
    };
});



describe('Testing a Controller that sums', function () {
  var $scope;

  beforeEach(module('myModule'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, service1,service2) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    spyOn(service2, 'theRealSum');

    $controller('ctl', { 
      $scope: $scope, 
      service1: service1
    });

  }));

  it('should resolve promise', function () {
    $scope.sumTheTwo(1,2);
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.result).toBe(3);
  });

});
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to mock `service2` if the controller doesn't directly depend on it. Just mock the response from `service1` to be as if it had called `service2`. Then in another set of tests you can test `service1` which _will_ need a mock of `service2`

Comment: Still need help with this?

Comment: No, I assumed that there's no way to mock service2 in the example above